# the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates

Tags: rust, traits

I'm struggling to wrap my head around usage of traits when these have associated types.

Here's a very simplified example:

```rust
pub trait Message {}

pub trait SendsMessages {
    type Message: Message;
    
    fn send(msg: Self::Message);
}

pub struct ImplementsSendsMessages {

}

impl<T> SendsMessages for ImplementsSendsMessages
where
    T: Message,
{
    type Message = T;

    fn send(id: T) {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As the compiler says, a generic parameter for an `impl Trait` must be constrained. Simply speaking, in the line `impl<T> SendsMessages for ImplementsSendsMessages` the `T` must appear elsewhere, but it does not.

Comment: Yeah, i figured that much out by going through `rustc --explain E0207`, but can't see how to actually fix it.

Comment: You probably want to [make `ImplementSendMessages` generic.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b6e2e66bc2280f165048d8dbb51ccc68)

Answer (score 18):

Whenever you write `impl<T>`, you're defining a generic implementation — a family of possible implementations. For every type you can fill in for `T`, that's a different implementation.

But every trait implementation must be uniquely identifiable from the trait and the implementing type: you can't have *more than one* `SendsMessages for ImplementsSendsMessages`, and that's what your code is trying to create.

You can define the trait with a type parameter instead of an associated type:

```rust
pub trait Message {}

pub trait SendsMessages<M: Message> {
    fn send(msg: M);
}

pub struct ImplementsSendsMessages {}

impl<T> SendsMessages<T> for ImplementsSendsMessages
where
    T: Message,
{
    fn send(id: T) {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

This is accepted because there's a *different trait* `SendsMessages<T>` for each `T` that exists, so it's unambiguous.

(It would also work if you had `struct ImplementsSendsMessage<T>`, since that's also unambiguous.)

Another way to look at this is that the *purpose* of associated types as opposed to type parameters is to be “outputs”, rather than “inputs”: once you pick a trait, an implementing type, and fill in all the parameters, the associated type is always *known and unique.* Your code fails because it's trying to fill in the associated type with “anything”, when it has to be a single concrete type.

Comment: Yep, this is spot on.  What threw me off is that I thought that if the `SendsMessages` was a generic it would bound it to one message type: not that case.  Thanks all